# Why does my Boston Terrier snort heavily at times?

Tags: dogs

On occasion, my Boston Terrier will snort very heavily, usually only for about 20 seconds.  Its very loud, and it sounds kind of like there is a lot of snot in his nose when he does it.

Someone once told me that "smushed face" dogs such as a Boston Terrier or French Bulldog do this.  But why?  I'm not concerned that its affecting his breathing or anything (he's done it for years I'm told), but why do these kind of dogs do this?

Comment: How does this differ from sneezing?

Comment: @keshlam what do you mean? His sneezes are nothing like this.

Comment: Wasn't sure; it seemed worth sanity-checking.

Comment: @keshlam nope, his sneezes are much different than what I am talking about.  If he does it again, I'll attempt to get a video for here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brachycephalic_syndrome explains the anatomical reasons why a brachycephalic (aka "Smushed-face) dog has more difficulty breathing than a dog with a typical skull structure:

> There are four different anatomical abnormalities that contribute to the disease, all of which occur more commonly in brachycephalic breeds: an elongated soft palate, stenotic nares, a hypoplastic trachea, and everted laryngeal saccules (a condition which occurs secondarily to the other abnormalities). Because all of these components make it more difficult to breathe, in situations of exercise, stress, or heat, an animal with these abnormalities may be unable to take deep or fast enough breaths to blow off carbon dioxide. This leads to distress and further increases respiratory rate and heart rate, creating a vicious circle that can quickly lead to a life-threatening situation.
>
> Dogs experiencing a crisis situation due to brachycephalic syndrome
>   typically benefit from oxygen, cool temperatures, sedatives, and in
>   some cases more advanced medical intervention including intubation.

While this article describes the extreme problems that may occur, your dog may have a milder form of some of the abnormalities that cause the snorting. You should just be aware that things can escalate, and take that in consideration when the dog is exercising, or the weather is extremely hot, etc.